# nodeJS ejs link_to undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

The error i am getting is "undefined is not a function". I think the problem lays in the app.local part about 10 lines into app.js.  I am new and following a tutorial and trying
to convert jade into ejs.  I have ejs and express-helpers. I have had some issues that were solved because stuff was depreciated. The problem is with the link_to. Any ideas or anybody run into a similar problem
This is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var helpers = require('express-helpers');
var ArticleProvider = require('./articleprovider-memory').ArticleProvider;

var app = module.exports = express();


app.configure(function(){
  app.locals({
    link_to : helpers.link_to
  });

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

var articleProvider= new ArticleProvider();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    articleProvider.findAll( function(error,docs){
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles:docs
        });
    });
});
```

and my index.ejs

```
<html>
<body>
        <h1> <%= title %> </h1>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) { 
        var article = articles[i]; %>
        <%= created_at = article.created_at %> <br>
        <%= link_to(title, 'blog/'+article._id) %> <br>
        <%= article.body %>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

THe answer is here https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers

I needed

```
require('express-helpers')();
```

didn't know i needed the extra parens